# How many way's to access formGroup field's - Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm using reactive forms in my angular project. Here I'm looking for code optimization to access fields. Usually now I'm accessing a field like below

```
this.myForm.controls['userId'].value
```

So here my doubt is like, is 'controls' mandatory to access a field from formGroup or is there any other way to access like simply `this.myForm.userId.value`. If any one have idea please help me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it's not possible you can access like  `this.myForm.controls['userId'].value`   or `this.myForm.controls('userId').value`

Answer (score 0):

That is one way of accessing that value. You can also try another one like this below:

this.myForm.get('userId').value